# Broken backdrop in Bootstrap UI modal

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

[image]

Can anyone help me with what is the issue that is causing this broken / irregular backdrop in background of overlay's or popup.

```
$scope.Modal = $modal.open({
                              animation: true,
                              templateUrl: '/Web/app/dashboard/Modal.html',
                              controller: 'Controller',
                              scope:$scope,
                              backdrop: 'static'
                          });
```

Tech Stack : Angular 1.3, Bootstrap, HTML 5 ,CSS 3

Comment: Can we have a fiddle which can reproduce the issue ?

Comment: I've tried in fiddle and it doesn't occur and this almost every case in my app whenever a popup opens it has this breaks on screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because of latest Chrome update 61. Here is the GitHub [link](https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/issues/1695) for the issue and Google [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/8qTXOIIl-qU)

Comment: Nice finding !!